# OpenGL ES 2.0 multithreading

Tags: opengl-es

I have been trying to use OpenGL ES 2.0 to make a photo viewing application. To optimize the code I'm changing the textures loaded with the objects as the user scrolls down. But image loading into the texture takes some time and thus the effect is not good. To solve the above problem I tried using multithreading with the following ways:

1. Create a separate context for the new thread and then share the resources (texture object) with the other context
2. Use multiple threads and a single context. Make the context current while executing gl commands in the threads.

But wasn't successful in either of them. So if anyone has tried similar things with opengl earlier, could you please tell which of the above ones would work and the things I need to pay attention to while doing the same? Also would FBO's and pbuffers be of any use in this case?

Thanks for any help.

Himanshu

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest keeping the OpenGL stuff in your primary thread, and delegating just the data loading to the worker thread.

Have, say, a circular buffer of image data objects that your worker thread can keep itself busy filling, but let your primary thread generate the textures from the image data as it needs them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think approach 1 is valid - you're not supposed to share resources across contexts.

I was very successful with something like your approach 2. My app, iSynth, does a lot of texture creation on the fly at the same time the app is handling network requests and trying to render a decent number of frames per second. I use two threads for OpenGL and they share a context.

One of these is a dedicated render thread. At the high level, it's a while loop that repeatedly calls my rendering code using whatever textures are available at the time.

The other does nothing but create texture resources for the render thread to use. Images are continuously downloaded on the main thread and queued up - this thread's sole mission in life is to eat through that queue and output GL textures.

This approach works well because one thread is strictly a producer and the other a consumer. I could foresee lots of ugly problems if you start trying to create textures on the render thread, or modify GL state on the texture thread. If you're having problems, I'd make sure you're properly setting up the shared context and making that context current on each thread. Also, if a thread utilizing that context goes away, I've found that it's necessary to call setCurrentContext: nil from that thread first.